# Execute function between 8AM to 7PM on Mon-Sat?

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, is it possible to execute `updateReport()` between  8AM to 7PM from Monday to Saturday?

```
window.setInterval(function() {
        // Update every 5 minutes
        updateReport();
},300000);
```

Comment: Set interval to, say, one minute. Run it 24/7. When your function fires check the time to see if you need to execute your report.

Comment: Yes I like to execute a function every 5 minuets but only between 8AM to 7PM from Monday to Saturday

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Comment: ...and you have your answer. What more do you need?

Comment: Looks like a cronjob is what you'd need for this rather then a js function that runs continually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with a number of conditions.
You have to have the webpage open between these hours.
If so, you can do the following code.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    if(now.getDay() !== 0){ //Sunday
        if(now.getHours() >= 8 && now.getHours() <= 19){
            updateReport();   
        }
    }
}, 300000);
```

But the question is, is this the best solution?
The answer to that is **no**.
I don't know what `updateReport` does, but I would look for a more server oriented solution to update the report.
The first solution that comes into mind is using a [cronjob](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) .
Or you can create a [windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute it.

Comment: updateReport() run ajax request, then php run curl to download updated report.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back  Does the curl script download the updated report to the browser of does it update the report itself? If it just downloads the updated report, why do you actually need to send the requests? If it also updates the report, a cronjob will be a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var currentDateTime = new Date();
  var day =  currentDateTime.getDay();

  var validCondition = currentDateTime.getHours() > 7 && currentDateTime.getHours() < 20 && day > 0;

  if(validCondition){
       // Update every 5 minutes
        updateReport();
  }
},300000);
```

Comment: `day < 6` condition will not come